# Pegar todos elementos que atendem uma condição

Tags: java, vector, indexof

Tenho alguns `Vector`:

```
public static Vector<Integer> id = new Vector<Integer>();
public static Vector<String> nome = new Vector<String>();
public static Vector<String> nascimento = new Vector<String>();
public static Vector<String> trabalho = new Vector<String>();
public static Vector<String> foto = new Vector<String>();
public static Vector<String> premios = new Vector<String>();
```

Atualmente estou usando  seguinte código para buscar um valor nesses `arrays`:

```
if(where.equals("id"))
    key = Record.id.indexOf(Integer.parseInt(value));
else if(where.equals("nome"))
    key = Record.nome.indexOf(value);
else if(where.equals("nascimento"))
    key = Record.nascimento.indexOf(value);
else if(where.equals("trabalho"))
    key = Record.trabalho.indexOf(value);
else if(where.equals("foto"))
    key = Record.foto.indexOf(value);
else if(where.equals("premios"))
    key = Record.premios.indexOf(value);
```

O problema é que no caso, o `indexOf` encontra somente a primeira ocorrência na lista, quero pegar o índice de todas ocorrências de um elemento, há algum método nativo do `Java` para isso? Ou só usando for e colocando os índices achados em um novo `Vector`?

Comment: Aparentemente, sim. Vai ter que usar laço de repetição para varrer todo o Vector e encontrar outras duplicatas.

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando o JDK 7, me diz que eu te dou outra resposta, espero ter ajudado, e se eu já tiver ajudado, não esqueça de marcar como resolvido, bons estudos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o java 8, você pode utilizar a API de streams e passar um predicado e retornar os elementos que atendem a determinada condição, segue o código abaixo:

```
public List<String> obtemFotos(String criterio) {
  return Record.fotos
    .stream()
    .filter(foto -> foto.equals(criterio))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Seria algo nessa linha, e você faria isso para cada coleção sua, acho que tem uma forma muito melhor de tratar esses vectors caso a caso, mas não vou entrar nesse assunto pois foge do escopo dessa pergunta.

Comment: Estou usando Java 7 no desenvolvimento, porém da para migrar para o 8. Mas eu fiz com um `for` por enquanto, enquanto aguardava a resposta.

Comment: Beleza, quando migrar, pode usar isso, fica muito melhor.